# Extending ORM classes in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to extend Query class in order to create function customContain() available in every Table model. How should I do it?

Comment: Without any knowledge of CakePHP, why not make a class between ShipmentTable and Table lets say MyTable which has the bleMethod() MyTable extends Table and ShipmentTable extends MyTable

Comment: To get this functionality one way is to use Trait in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use that BleMethod() in all table models in cakephp. Where I have to add code of that function? Where I have to implements BleMethod?

Unlike Cake2 Cake3 does not feature an application level class like `AppModel` from where all other classes inherit from. So you have two options:

- [Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)
- [Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html)

The behavior can be loaded globally to all models by using the `Model.initialize` event. And then loading the behavior inside the events callback. Read these pages:

- [Creating a behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#creating-a-behavior)
- [Event system](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html)
- [Model / Table callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

#### But that's not what you want

`customContain()` indicates for me that you want to setup some contains very often. Well, use finders.

Finders can be combined:

```
$this->Table->find('foo')->find('myContains')->all();
```

Each custom find will add something to the query object. You can add your custom contains this way.

Read [Custom Finder Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods).

Comment: Finders seem to be what I need, but I will be using one finder in many tables, so correct me if I am wrong. I should create a new Behavior and put there all my finder methods?

Comment: This would work, yes, but a trait as well. Finders are a very nice tool to combine queries as needed and very flexible. For example I have a "findActive" trait to find only active = true flagged records.

Comment: As @burzum said, there's no `AppModel` in Cake3. But it's entirely possible to make your own `\App\Model\Table\AppTable` class that extends `Table`, and which your tables can extend. Whether that might be useful depends very much on the specifics of your situation.

Comment: Yes, but 3rd party code in plugins for example won't inherit from that class. That's why you would use events and behaviors.